# Ruby on Rails, delayed_job serializing incorrect datetime as GMT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, delayed-job

I have some code that seems to execute improperly when it is serialized and run with delayed_job.  To get the necessaries out of the way, I am running Ubuntu 11.04, Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.0.4.

I have a datetime field in one of my tables that obviously stores the date and time of a particular event.  In my RoR application, I use this field through the application calling strftime on it to format it in different ways.  The output of this formatting is correct on the web page.

I am also using delayed_job to put this same field into an email that is sent out (triggered via some action).  When the email arrives, it appears that it has somehow been formatted as GMT.  For example, if the date time was supposed to be 11-12-2011 15:30:00 (3:30 PM) in the database, the email would read 11-12-2011 22:30:00 (10:30 PM).

I looked in the database and found somethings that are interesting:

- The datetime in the database is `2011-11-12 22:30:00`
- The app, when displayed via the web, formats the data properly as 11-12-2011, 3:30 PM
- The email, formats the data properly as 11-12-2011, 10:30 PM
- When I run a small ruby file that simply prints the date and time

  p Time.now

I get this the correct output (local, non GMT time)

```
Mon Aug 15 10:15:27 -0600 2011
```

When I look at what is in the serialized yaml for the delayed_jobs table, I can see that the date field is formatted as

```
2011-11-12 22:30:00 Z
```

In my application.rb, I have

```
config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

and in my environment.rb, I have

```
timezone = "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
```

Can any one help me figure out what is going on here?  I am relatively new to RoR, so this may be a super obvious, easy question.  If you need any more debug information, please let me know and I can post it up.  Similarly, if my question is unclear, I can try to clar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the date object to a string before serializing.

Comment: D'oh. delayed_job wouldn't know anything about time zones and would use GMT after unserialization.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved explicitly specifying the method `in_time_zone` in the view 
example: `@my_obj.created_at.in_time_zone`.

I know it is not elegant, but so far I have not found better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the timezone in the database.  If it's MySQL, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: James - it appears that the timezone is set correctly for MySQL.  I ran a `select now();` and it returned the date and time proper for my timezone (Mountain).  Is there a different way to check it that I need to try?

Comment: Then MySQL is set correctly.  There must be something else wrong, not sure what.